# GitLab: You are not allowed to access master! After moving gitlab to another server

Tags: linux, git, ssh

I'm moving my gitlab instance to another server and I run to problem.
clone is working fine, but push is throwing error, and I can't figure out where is problem.
In gitlab logs is nothing usefull.

```
git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 351 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master! 
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To git@server:user/repo.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@server:user/repo.git'
```

I don't know where is problem, I change little bit configuration. Repos and satelites where on previous server symlinks to `/media/data/git/repositories` now is `/home/git` symlink to `/media/disk/git` But i don't think that is the problem.

EDIT://
gitlab:check is everything OK also gitlab-shell check is OK

Comment: you need to import ssh keys again

Comment: I've add new ssh key and use it. When I do git clone, I'm asked for ssh password and clone is fine.

Comment: Open the project page, go to "Commits", choose "Branches" tab, and check the Protected-section - maybe someone has restricted the access for master branch.

Comment: That is not problem i have only master branch in most projects. I now have two separate gits on one domain, one is on another port, and when I try push on old working domain everything works, but new one wont.(of course I made clone from them separately)

Comment: howdy, got similar problem, the https-protocol is ok but the git-protocol keep denying the push. did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 5):

[TL:DR]

After loads of frustrated hours and lots of trial and error, I found a solution to this problem (for me anyway).

cd /home/git/repositories

rm -rf */*/hooks/update

[Explanation]

I upgraded from 6.3 -> 6.9 sequentially with no problems on the front end, but (silly me) didn't check push & pulls each time so I don't know exactly where this started happening. I suspect after the 6.7 upgrade. Both SSH and HTTP push & pulls stopped working but with slightly different errors. I searched for symlinks on the repositories directory like some threads said, I also ran chmod's and chown's to ensure git had access to all the repositories. I also checked NGINX config's to ensure it was pointing to the right IP/FQHN. No dice, same errors. I finally found [this issue](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3584) which lead me check a few things and finally to the solution above.

I'm not sure if this fix is because the 'update' files in each repo's hooks folder were symlinks, or because of something in the files themselves, but now I can push & pull as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Bitnami version and the previously configured `config.yml` file pointed to a **symlink** rather than the actual directory.

I Fixed this changing the  gitlab-shell `config.yml` to point to the real repository directory.

```
# repos_path: "/opt/gitlab-6.3.0-1/apps/gitlab/repositories"
```

to

```
repos_path: "/home/git"
```

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh install for me, I had *serious* issues when /home was a symlink to /usr/home.

`gitlab-shell/config.yml` contained `repos_path: "/home/git/repositories` which caused the same error output you referenced above.  Putting the canonical path in it's place corrected the issue.  If you watch the `http` traffic you'll see two GET's, one to `//api/v3/internal/allow/allowed` with arguments `key_id`, `action`, `ref`, and `project`

In my case `project` was `rpaisley/asdf` on the first call, and `usr/rpaisley/asdf` on the second which failed.

I'm going to drill into this a bit and see if I can at least get Gitlab to detect that it's not a canonical path and warn the user before simply not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and thought @Kythrin 's answer solved it but stumbled upon another related problem and this might be a fitting place to post the solution:

Yes indeed, now 'push' to the master repository works, however the update hooks are needed to automatically close issues via commit & push (for example, `git commit -m "closes #1"` should close Issue #1 of that specific repository). This didn't work when the update hooks were deleted. And if the update hooks were not deleted, the push didn't work again. After hours of troubleshooting, the problem was that the remote repository could not be cloned using the standard way via

> ssh://git@git.[myserver].com:[portNr]/[git-project]/[git-repository].git

, instead a directory prefix was needed (note: only on OS X 10.8+, Windows 8 worked fine) to clone the correct repository.

As far as I understood the reason for this behaviour was that an already existing public ssh authorization key for the git user didn't have the commands to retrieve infos about the remote rempository, it's relative path inside of the parent directory etc.. instead of getting that info from the correct, remote **gitlab** user who already had the necessary commands. So instead of using the key with the gitlab commands the previously created one was used.
I suspect because git installs with OS X/XCode and when we setup Gitlab on our server later and connected, the public key of the git user was not updated?

Now cloning with only specifying the relative address of the remote repository works as well as using the update hooks to close issues conveniently via commit.

(Should a technically more experienced user or one with english as first language be able to explain that problem and the reason why better, please feel free to edit or suggest edits to my post)

The solution is written in the [Trouble Shooting Guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#could-not-read-from-remote-repository):

---

### Could not read from remote repository

### Error: clone from ssh doesn't work

The SSH path for my project doesn't work because it is missing the repositories directory.

> git@git.myserver.com:mygroup/proj1.git

should be

> git@git.myserver.com:repositories/mygroup/proj1.git

Problem: Described in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3686. The public key for the git user already existed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys before you setup gitlab, the key for gitlab should begin with:

> command="/home/git/gitlab/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell
>   key-2",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty

Solution: Remove the keys which do not start with the above command from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 0):

I also did an upgrade over more than one step to 6.9. and run into this problem. It seems connected with the following issue in the GitLab Community Edition:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/333

The update hook in the repositories is a symlink, so I comment the security check in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/lib/gitlab_update.rb` (what is the source of the symlink):

```
10:27:34me@hogwarts:/home/git/gitlab-shell$ git diff lib/gitlab_update.rb 
diff --git a/lib/gitlab_update.rb b/lib/gitlab_update.rb
index 4b0673f..174bbad 100644
--- a/lib/gitlab_update.rb
+++ b/lib/gitlab_update.rb
@@ -36,13 +36,14 @@ class GitlabUpdate
     # get value from it
     ENV['GL_ID'] = nil

-    if api.allowed?('git-receive-pack', @repo_name, @actor, @ref_name, @oldrev, @newrev, forced_push?)
-      update_redis
-      exit 0
-    else
-      puts "GitLab: You are not allowed to access #{@ref_name}!"
-      exit 1
-    end
+    #if api.allowed?('git-receive-pack', @repo_name, @actor, @ref_name, @oldrev, @newrev, forced_push?)
+    #  update_redis
+    #  exit 0
+    #else
+    #  puts "GitLab: You are not allowed to access #{@ref_name}!"
+    #  exit 1
+    update_redis
+    exit 0
   end
```

It's a hack, but works for me now. Hopefully somebody or me finds some spare time to dig deeper into this issue.