# GIT and GITLAB in Debian Wheezy

Tags: git, debian, gitlab

I'm news in git and gitlab. I've installed it from the officiel installation.
Trying to push some project via sourcetree for example, I've this result

```
`git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream    origin master:master
 Pushing to git@xxx.xxxxx.xx:/home/git/repositories/root/all.git

remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master![K
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master[K
```

To git@xxx.xxxxx.xx:/home/git/repositories/root/all.git
    ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxx.xxxxx.xx:/home/git/repositories/root/all.git' `

Someone have an idea?

Thank's

Comment: would http://stackoverflow.com/q/19510954/6309 help?

Comment: Thank's for your response. I've changed the repos_path to /projetgitlab/ with all privileges for all users but the same result.

Comment: My gitlab version is 6-4 stable. I note that I can create project and nac navigate to the URL for administration of gitlab.

Comment: Would cloning/pushing using an https url would work better than an ssh one? Or can you try and update gitlab to a latest version, to see if the issue persists?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in the prompt: mkdir aaa
cd test
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin git@xxx.xxx.Xxx:user_dev/aaa.git
git push -u origin master 

The result tell me that this is does not appear to be a git repository. What's wrong??

Comment: I would rather declare a new empty repo on gitlab, and clone it locally, which set the remote origin for you, add, commit and push.

Comment: If you try to push without having declared a repo first on gitlab, you will get the error message you saw.

Comment: I've create this repo using the default URL of gitlab. Then, I use a git client to clone it localy and to push the data.

Comment: Clone:
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false clone --recursive git@xxx.xxxxx.XX:/projetgitlab/userdev/aaa.git D:\e
Cloning into 'D:\e'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Push:
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to access master![K
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master[K
To git@xx.xxxxx.XX:/projetgitlab/userdev/aaa.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xx.xxxxx.XX:/projetgitlab/userdev/aaa.git'

Comment: Since you are cloning a repo using ssh, do you have published your ssh public key on your gitlab account setting, in order to authenticate you (as the owner of the repo you have created and to which you are pushing)?

Comment: Is the shh-keygen -t rsa -C "usermail@test.com" are you teling?

Comment: It is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11771907/6309. Don't put any passphrase to your private key, in order to test it.

Comment: Try to push and  to generate a ssh key, this is the result: Access denied.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: You must first add your public key to your GitLab profile before doing any push.

Comment: Ok. Thank's for your response. I'll tray it and will return here.

Comment: the problem is now solved.
Thank's to all.
Vononka

Comment: Great. I have added an answer to summarize those comments. Is there a specific step you did, and that I missed in my answer?

Comment: No, I've just follow your answer and now, it work perfectly. Thank you VonC

Answer (score 0):

After my comments, The [OP Andry Vononka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2886186/andry-vononka) did:

- generate an ssh key ([using ssh-keygen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11771907/6309))
- add the public key to the GitLab Account Settings ([illustrated here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-gitlab-user-interface-to-manage-projects), and in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54mxyLo3Mqk) from [GitLab screencast](https://www.gitlab.com/2014/03/04/add-ssh-key-screencast/))
- make sure he is the owner of the repo he is pushing to.